# Is there a way to call a method when the picture is taken

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

Im new to mobile development and im working on a app and for that app i need to get the time at the exact moment a picture is taken. I want to get the exact time from a server so i need to call a method because the time in the exif data is not accurate enough. I was working with a camera-intent but this shows the result and needs a confirmation before the next code is called. Is there a way to call code or a method when the picture is taken when using a camera-intent.

This is the code i have right now. Im calling dispatchTakePictureIntent and that method will start the intent. onActivityResult will then get the result of the camera but the moment this method is called is after the confirmation.

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
    PackageManager pckMgr = getPackageManager();

    if (pckMgr.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera werkt niet ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
        // Get Extra from the intent
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        // Get the returned image from extra
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

So id like to call a method in which i save the exact time the picture is taken. I've also searched if there was a way to get rid of this confirmation screen but there doesn't seem to be one but this would be a good solution as well.

Comment: you have to create your own custom camera class . for reference https://github.com/wuapnjie/ACamera

Comment: dont get the bitmap directly it might be blurry 
use this https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Comment: yeah, using camera2 api is the best approach, since when you open camera intent it is hard to track, since you are out of the scope of your application

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can create one method which call every second in background

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //do something
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

when u call camera open click and then u need to observe if there is some storage increment happens or not in DCIM folder or in storage. Directly i don't this it's possible in system camera or you can use camera api in your app

Answer (score 0):

Because you use native camera application, you have fewer controls over it.
Maybe you can implement your own camera application, and when you take photos inside your application, you can do what you mention easily.

Answer (score 0):

The moment your onActivityResult called with RESULT_OK means that you successfully captured photo so you can get current time inside onActivityResult using  System.currentTimeMillis().